Two PUBLIC Views in Stored Procedure - One Succeeds, One Errors?
If user A creates a view and grants READ on it to PUBLIC.
SQL>create view A.a_public as select 3 id from dual;

View created.

SQL>select * from A.a_public;
        ID
----------
         3

SQL>grant read on A.a_public to public;

Grant succeeded.

Then user B can create a stored procedure selecting from A's view and successfully execute that stored procedure.
SQL>create or replace procedure B.b_public
  2      as
  3          num NUMBER;
  4      begin
  5          select id into num from A.a_public;
  6          dbms_output.put_line('~' || num || '~');
  7      end;
  8  /

Procedure created.

SQL>show errors
No errors.
SQL>set serveroutput on
SQL>exec B.b_public();
~3~

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>

READ of SYS.V_$RESTORE_POINT has been granted to PUBLIC.
For the stored procedure below, why does the compilation succeed, but the execution fail?
SQL>select count(*) from dba_tab_privs where table_name = 'V_$RESTORE_POINT' and grantor = 'SYS' and grantee = 'PUBLIC' and privilege = 'READ';
  COUNT(*)
----------
         1
SQL>create or replace procedure w_restore_point
  2      as
  3          num_scn NUMBER;
  4      begin
  5          select scn into num_scn from
  6          SYS.v_$restore_point
  7          where rownum = 1;
  8          dbms_output.put_line(num_scn);
  9      end;
 10  /

Procedure created.

SQL>show errors
No errors.
SQL>set serveroutput on
SQL>exec w_restore_point();
BEGIN w_restore_point(); END;

*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01031: insufficient privileges
ORA-06512: at "SCHEMA_NAME.W_RESTORE_POINT", line 5
ORA-06512: at line 1

SQL>

Using Oracle 19c EE.
EDIT
4.8.1.8.1 Roles Used in Named Blocks with Definer's Rights

All roles are disabled in any named PL/SQL block that executes with
definer's rights.

I am assuming this is really supposed to read "All roles except PUBLIC are disabled...".  Otherwise, definer rights stored procedures that use dbms_output, for example, would not execute successfully if the privilege domain of the definer (with regard to dbms_output) was only EXECUTE on dbms_output being granted to PUBLIC.
EDIT 2
I now realize the issue may be isolated to v_$restore_point.
Even though catalog.sql > cdfixed.sql are analogous -
create or replace view v_$restore_point as
  select * from v$restore_point;
create or replace public synonym v$restore_point
  for v_$restore_point;
grant read on v_$restore_point to public;

create or replace view v_$session_connect_info as
  select * from v$session_connect_info;
create or replace public synonym v$session_connect_info
   for v_$session_connect_info;
grant read on v_$session_connect_info to public;

the issue does not occur for SYS.v_$session_connect_info.
SQL>create or replace procedure w_session_connect_info
  2      as
  3          num_sid NUMBER;
  4      begin
  5          select sid into num_sid from
  6          SYS.v_$session_connect_info
  7          where rownum = 1;
  8          dbms_output.put_line(num_sid);
  9      end;
 10  /

Procedure created.

SQL>show errors
No errors.
SQL>set serveroutput on
SQL>exec w_session_connect_info();
5

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>

This wordpress article discusses that it simply may be sufficient to have a role named SELECT_CATALOG_ROLE even if there are no privileges granted to that role due to the hardcoding of a literal 'SELECT_CATALOG_ROLE' predicate.

Looks like you'd have to grant select_catalog_role privilege to procedure which is using v_$restore_point.
grant select_catalog_role to procedure B.b_public;


True, but Code Based Access Controls were not required for A.a_public.  Why the difference?  If the definer of w_restore_point really had insufficient privileges, then why did it compile (it's static SQL)?

v_$restore_point is not even granted to SELECT_CATALOG_ROLE.
From catalog.sql > cdfixed.sql:

create or replace public synonym v$restore_point for v_$restore_point;

grant read on v_$restore_point to public;

Or does this have to do with the hard coding of the 'SELECT_CATALOG_ROLE' predicate as identified here?
